# how to not bounce, postfix to not return "not found" when the address does not exist

Tags: postfix, mx-record, email-server

I want to enable a second MX with the same domain, with some users on different MX.
how is this to be done?
how do I tell postfix to not bounce, postfix to not return "not found" when the address does not exist on the server, and possible to check out on the other server or things?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer *NO* it cannot be done, as `MX` works on `DNS` level and it's up to `MTA` to handle mailboxes, but you should probably read more about [MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) and how it works.